# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a whitlisted role to do a command and i puted this line

```js
if (!message.guild.cache.roles.find(role => role.id === '873595824469344256')) return;
```

Error I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });
const config = require('./config.json');
const prefix = "g!"

bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.tag} bot is online`);
});

bot.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.content === prefix + "help") {
        if (!message.guild.cache.roles.find(role => role.id === '873595824469344256')) return;
        let helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Help Guide')
        .setAuthor('Request : ' + `${message.author.username}`)
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Ban Usage', value: `${prefix}ban **id** | **reason** | **time** \n**__Exemple__** : ${prefix}ban id ALT-F4+Troll (without espace) 32H`},
            { name: 'Warn Usage', value: `${prefix}warn **id** | **reason** | **time** \n**__Exemple__** : ${prefix}warn id Bunny-Hope (without espace) warn-1/2/3`},
        )
        .setFooter('© ©');
    
    message.reply({ embeds: [helpembed] });
    };
});
```

Comment: `message.guild.cache.roles.find` should be `message.guild.roles.cache.find`

Answer (score 2):

Change your

```js
if (!message.guild.cache.roles.find(role => role.id === '873595824469344256')) return;
```

to:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has("873595824469344256")) return`
```